# user name rails devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am new to rails. I was looking for an answer before deciding to post a question. The 2 answers I found didn't work for me.

So I have a model "post" and "devise" gem installed and configured.

then I added "username"  into users

`rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string`

then relationships

user --> has many, post --> belong to user.

but I'm stuck.

How exactly do I retrieve a username to render with post?

<%= post.user.username =%> ?

What else needs to be done?

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :postbody, :posttitle
  validates_presence_of :postbody, :posttitle
  belongs_to :user

end
```

user.rb

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base`

```
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :posts
```

end

Comment: please be specific and descriptive about your questions, problems that you have.

Comment: the problem is I want to render the username ones a post has been created. So it will show next to the post

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned about what type of error you are having.
But it seams that your may be having error about undefined attribute.
make username accessible by adding `attr_accessible :username` in `User` model.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did put username into attr_accessible. The error is `code`(undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass)

Comment: seems like your post doesn't have any associated user with it

Comment: thanks everyone. What I have done is i put into the post table `user_id`. Then into post controller create `@post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])` , post show `<%= @post.user.username %>`  . Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean "devise", right?
I'm not sure about your error (maybe show the whole migration), but I would recommend to do a reset on your database rather than adding a migration.
Just put

```
t.string :username
```

to the create_users migration. Then

```
rake db:migrate:reset
```

Comment: Hi, yes it's devise, sorry. OK i reset it and it wipe off all my foo posts here is my migration `class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, 
    t.string :username
    t.string :name
  end
end
`

Comment: It would be nice to see your models (post and users) and the create users migration. Btw: You don't need to have a "AddUsernameToUsers"-migration, when you have no problems with reseting.

Comment: what happens, when you write in the console (open with `rails console`) and type in `post.user_id` ? What is the exact error message? ALso write `<%= post.user.username %>` nocht `<%= post.user.username =%>`

Comment: `Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.12)
irb(main):001:0> post.user_id
NameError: undefined local variable or method `post' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
2/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
      `

Comment: You first need to have the variable "post". So for example "post = Post.new(:posttitle => "irgendwas", :postbody => "something"). Than you can cann post.user or post.user_id

Comment: your post is not being associated with user.. try to make post via user like this, `current_user.posts.create(:posttitle => 'test', :postbody => 'test')` and then fetch this post from db. Now you will not get any nill class error on calling `post.user.username`

Comment: Another tip: Put 'gem annotate' in your Gemfile and call from console `bundle install && annotate`. Then your models will be annotated, which means you can see in your user.rb or post.rb how it is represented in your database